# How apply a filter on MediaPlayer using a SurfaceView?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediaplayer

I need perform a filter on draw of one video playing on android (MediaPlayer), this filter just will turn the background to transparent, but how I can read the bytes to process? because android seems don't run alpha channel movies :(

I need this to put a video in a fullscreen overlaying the camera preview (AR). That's why I need the movie background transparent.

My idea be send the MediaPlayer frame data (bitmap data) to NDK process, then back a processed bitmap to surfaceview.

PS: Android API8, target 2.2+

Follow My code bellow:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MovieSurfaceView extends SurfaceView {

    public MovieSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        super.onDraw(c);
    }

}

/** The main activity for the ImageTargets sample. */
public class ImageTargets extends Activity  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    private MovieSurfaceView mPreview;

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    private SurfaceHolder holder;

    private String videoPath = "/LAST.3g2";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        DebugLog.LOGD("ImageTargets::onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initApplicationAR();
    }

    private void initApplicationAR()
    {        

        mPreview = new MovieSurfaceView(this);

        addContentView(mPreview, new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        //        holder = mGlView.getHolder();
        holder = mPreview.getHolder();
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        holder.addCallback(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);

        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 

        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() 
        {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
                mp.start();
            }
        }
        );

        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
        {

            @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
                mp.reset();
            }
        }
        );

        iniPlayer();
    }


    @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }  


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a player using NDK + OpenGL (when you compile the player set the rgb565 = 0, this enable the alpha channel)

http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/

**Now the solution to my problem bellow:**

http://code.google.com/p/javacv/

```
import java.io.File;

import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;

public class TestCV{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File f = new File("input.mp4");
        FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(f);

        final CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("My Image");

        canvas.showImage(grabber.grab());

    }
}
```

After just lock the canvas and work with bytes, like we can do on CameraPreview canvas,

Thanks for all who helped,

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest sending both movie frames and camera frames to OpenGL. You don't explain how you are going to choose the alpha filter on the movie frames, but with OpenGL you can implement many filters on GPU with shaders.

Comment: The problem be the android target mate, I can't use SurfaceTexture to send the video frames to openGL, some alternative to put the movie frames to texture?

Comment: You are right, with SurfaceTexture it is much easier, but I have implemented similar tasks on 2.2. I used camera preview callback, glTexSubImage2D, and shaders to convert yuv to rgb.

Comment: the camera be OK, but about video file? mp4, 3gp, etc, how you know some trick to send to the current frame to openGL?

Comment: I was using a custom video decoder based on ffmpeg. But can't you take the Canvas from onDraw

Comment: Can you share with me? on your custom video decoder you can process the frames of movie? I meant, send to openGL thing? Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not open source. But you can find ffmpeg built for Android on [github](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg)

Comment: Right, I will try more here, now with ffmpeg, thanks anyway, I will post the result here

Comment: Dude, do you think possible to touch the android 2.2 video with alpha channel?

Comment: Yes, be possible with ffmpeg RGB8888